# Rohklin’s formula and $\beta$ expansions

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems

I've been reading K. Dajani and C. Kraaikamp's paper [From greedy to lazy expansions and their driving dynamics](http://dutiosc.twi.tudelft.nl/~cork/monthly.pdf). In the last page previous to the references, they mention that the entropy of the map $T_{\alpha, \beta}(x) = \beta x + \alpha$ is $\log(\beta)$. They mention this fact follows from the *Rohklin’s formula for calculating the entropy*. What I would like to know is a reference where this formula is stated and proved.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the formula 
$$
h_\mu(f) = \int \log |f'|\,d\mu
$$
for the entropy of an absolutely continuous $f$-invariant measure $\mu$ on the unit interval which goes back to Rokhlin (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=143873), also see Ledrappier (http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=627788).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I needed. Also, thanks for making clear that the formula is measure theoretic.